# Mapbox GL make a map using a previously generated map object

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox

I am creating a map in my React application using the following code (the minimal reproducible version is the example from Mapbox given at the bottom of [this page](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/)):

```
const mapboxGlMap = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: mapContainer.current,
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [6.7, 50.3],
    zoom: 14,
});
```

I then later want to recreate the map elsewhere using the `mapboxGLMap` object (which will have all of the users map changes e.g. layers added, zoom/pan etc.) Is there a way to do this using Mapbox GL?

In the [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/) there is no mention but I am wondering if anyone has a clever way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. I store the map object as React context so it is available throughout my components. I then have a useEffect hook in the map component that detects:

1. when the map is being rendered for the first time, and
2. when the map is being re-rendered

On first render I call a function `initMap()` that create the map in the normal way and sets the map object context.

For following renders I call `reInitMap()` which references this object and uses it to remake the map as it was last seen by the user. Then reset the context to this new map object so that the map context is always the latest even after any number of re-renders. An example of this is the `zoom` and `center` attributes as well as using `MapState.getStyle()` and `mapboxGlMap.setStyle()` for the sources and layers.

```
// within reInitMap()
const { lng, lat } = MapState.getCenter();
const mapboxGlMap = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: mapContainer.current,
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [lng, lat],
    zoom: MapState.getZoom(),
});
```